# How to create navigation menu with png image beneath the text

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm an uncoded website designer looking for how to create this navigation bar:

[image]

To become this:

[image]

I already have the image asset, just don't know how to code and where put the code.

[image]

Current website design (using wordpress): http://beta.mkp.co.id/shop/

Answer (score 0):

you may use **before** element like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  padding;
  0 10px;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ec3P.png);
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-size: 100%;
}

ul li:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```